# How to display controller response on twig template?

Tags: craft3, plugin-development, twigextension

In the plugin, I created a form and after the process, return the below response from the controller and redirect to the template. I am trying to print the response to the template but it's not working.

```
$multi_res  =array("status"=>True, "message"=>'Sucess');
return $this->renderTemplate(
      'craft-handle/test.twig',
      $multi_res            
     );
```

Comment: Can you post your twig template? The controller code looks correct, so the issue is most likely in the template. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I want to print the response on test.twig template but I am not sure how to print it. I need help to print responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller looks ok, though I would clean it up a bit and use more expressive variable names to reduce the surface area for bugs:

```php
$templateVariables = [
    'status' => true,
    'message' => 'Sucess'
];
return $this->renderTemplate(
    'craft-handle/test.twig',
    $templateVariables
);
```

Now you will have access to the variables `status` and `message` in your `test.twig`:

```
{# templates/craft-handle/test.twig #}

<h1>{{ status ? 'Success' : 'Failure' }}</h1>
<p>Message: {{ message }}</p>
```

Comment: It's working. Thanks for the quick reply.